# How do I return such an multi-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

It is a little bit complicated:
`int[][] generate(int[][] input)` creates a new array with the same structure as input.
The contents of each row are written on the next row. The contents of the last row get in the first row. If the length of a row is too short for all of the moved numbers, the remaining numbers are added on each element of this row. If the length of the line is too long for all shifted numbers, the the remaining fields are filled with the average of the numbers in this row.

For example: input:

```
int[][] test1 = { {1, 2, 3, -4, -9}, {-20, 13}, {30, 19, 12, -12} }
```

output:

```
{ {30, 19, 12, -12, 12}, {-9, -8}, {-20, 13, -3, -3} }
```

I would be really grateful, if you could give me some advices, for example how do my if statements have to look like.

Comment: Could you demonstrate, step by step, how you got from the example input to the example output?

Comment: 1. You shift the rows one row down, except the last row, this row becomes the top row. 2. While you shift, you will realise that the row you are currently shifting is longer than the row next, in this case  the remaining numbers are added together  and then added to all of the elements of this (longer) row and then placed to the row down . 3. But if the row you want to shift is shorter than the row under it or next to it, then all numbers of this row builds the average and are appended to the shorter row

Comment: P.s You have to imagine the rows like a matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation of the *rotate* method. I've added explanations on what the code is doing as comments:

```
public static int[][] rotate(int[][] matrix) {
    int[][] result = new int[matrix.length][];

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
        // if we exceed the length of the result matrix, let's rotate back to 0 (first row).
        int indexResult = i + 1 == matrix.length ? 0 : i + 1;
        result[indexResult] = new int[matrix[indexResult].length];

        // The row in which to insert is shorter than the row to be inserted
        if(result[indexResult].length < matrix[i].length) {
            // Let's find the sum of all the remaining (overflow) numbers.
            int sumNumber = 0;
            for(int j = matrix[i].length - result[indexResult].length - 1; j < matrix[i].length; ++j) {
                sumNumber += matrix[i][j];
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < result[indexResult].length; ++j) {
                result[indexResult][j] = matrix[i][j] + sumNumber;
            }
        } else if(result[indexResult].length > matrix[i].length) {  // The row in which to insert is longer
            double average = 0.0;
            int j = 0;
            while(j < matrix[i].length) {
                average += matrix[i][j];
                result[indexResult][j] = matrix[i][j];
                ++j;
            }
            average = average / matrix[i].length;
            while(j < result[indexResult].length) {
                result[indexResult][j] = (int) average;
                ++j;
            }
        } else { // The length is the same. just copy the array;
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; ++j) {
                result[indexResult][j] = matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

For input:

```
int[][] test1 = { {1, 2, 3, -4, -9}, {-20, 13}, {30, 19, 12, -12} };
```

The output is:

```
{ {30, 19, 12, -12, 12}, {-9, -8}, {-20, 13, -3, -3} }
```

Comment: Damn, thank u very much

Comment: @stacy glad I could help.